# nestjs mongoose .insertMany is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I'm stuck with using "insertMany". Can anyone explain how to use this method?
Nest official docs says nothing about this realization. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb

*upload.model.ts*

```
import { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';

export const Upload = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  usernameCreate: { type: String, required: true },
  dateCreate: { type: Date },
});

export interface IUpload extends Document {

  readonly _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId;
  readonly name: string;
  readonly dateCreate: Date;
  readonly usernameCreate: string;
}
```

*upload.service.ts*

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IUpload } from './upload.model';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Upload') private readonly uploadModel: Model<IUpload>
  ) {}

  async create({ files, body }): Promise<IUpload> {
    const arr = files.map((file) => {
      return {
        name: file.filename,
        dateCreate: body.dateCreate,
        usernameCreate: body.usernameCreate,
      };
    });
    const createUploads = new this.uploadModel();
    return createUploads.insertMany(arr);
  }
}
```

*terminal*

```
TypeError: createUploads.insertMany is not a function
```

*packages*

```
"@nestjs/mongoose": "^7.2.0",
"mongoose": "^5.11.9",
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized what **Document** doesn't have this method. Instead this I need to call it from **Model**

```
async create({ files, body }): Promise<any> {
    const arr = files.map((file) => {
      return {
        name: file.filename,
        dateCreate: body.dateCreate,
        usernameCreate: body.usernameCreate,
      };
    });
    return this.uploadModel.insertMany(arr);
  }
```

Comment: @Noob_Mern_Dev check this data by console.log :)

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error and i found that i am using the new keyword which should not be present at the time of insertMany.

```
return await this.bookingSlotsRespository.create(availableSlots);
```

and it works for me.

- availableSlots is an array of object which i have to save.

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new instance for the model try this

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { IUpload } from './upload.model';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Upload') private readonly uploadModel: Model<IUpload>
  ) {}

  async create({ files, body }): Promise<IUpload> {
    const arr = files.map((file) => {
      return {
        name: file.filename,
        dateCreate: body.dateCreate,
        usernameCreate: body.usernameCreate,
      };
    });
    await this.uploadModel().insertMany(arr);
    return {message:"success"}
  }
}
```